# Universal flat connection

Tags: vector-bundles

Existence of universal bundles with given structural group abound.
In the smooth category:

What is a reference for existence of a universal (bundle with flat connection}?

Comment: Do you mean universal in the category of flat vector bundles or general flat bundles?

Comment: The only reasonable notion of universality in this context that I know is the one of the universal covering: Suppose that $X$ is a connected CW complex, $u=(\tilde X\to X)$ is the universal covering. Then every flat vector bundle $E\to X$ "comes" from $u$ via the associated bundle construction. I do not think you will get anything better.